# --job_property in Bigquery command line

Tags: google-bigquery

Can you give me an example of how we can use --job_property option in bq command line and how it will be useful?

**This is my script**

```
query1="bq query --job_id=${Job_Name}_date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S'_$(uuidgen -r) --job_property=X --apilog=$Log_File_Path/${Workflow_Name}_date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S'.txt --batch=false --use_legacy_sql=false --quiet --nouse_cache --format=csv '$Select_Query'| awk '{if(NR>1)print}'" eval Query_Output=\$($query1); echo $Query_Output
```

Regards,
Sreekanth

Comment: Have you tried reading BigQuery documentation? I suggest you do that and post an example of what you tried and expected result if something not working (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bq-command-line-tool)

Comment: Thanks Tamir . Yes, I have tried Bigquery Documentation and google search and it is does not carry much information for this attribute and how it can used.   I also tried using this propert in bq query and checked the apilog output. But did not understand how to best define (syntax) and use it.

Comment: Please add to your question what you tried and what not working this will help answer your question

Comment: is this the right way?


query1="bq query --job_id=${Job_Name}_`date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S'`_$(uuidgen -r) --job_property=X --apilog=$Log_File_Path/${Workflow_Name}_`date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S'`.txt --batch=false --use_legacy_sql=false --quiet --nouse_cache --format=csv '$Select_Query'| awk '{if(NR>1)print}'"

eval Query_Output=\$\($query1\);

echo $Query_Output

Comment: I update your question and added an answer to guide you to the next step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Working Example**

```
sh-3.2# ./bq query --nouse_legacy_sql --batch=false --job_property=X --apilog=log.txt 'select count(*) from `projectId.dataset.table`'
Waiting on bqjob_r587a6f7334c724e6_00000169292be4f3_1 ... (1s) Current status: DONE
+----------+
|   f0_    |
+----------+
| 29485761 |
+----------+
```

Note: You can do `less log.txt` to check full execution details

**Non-working example with an error**

```
sh-3.2# ./bq query --nouse_legacy_sql --batch=false --job_property=X --apilog=log_date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S'.txt 'select count(*) from `project.dataset.table`'
Error in query string: Error processing job 'project:bqjob_r18f282eae4979c98_00000169292c43fc_1': Syntax error: Unexpected "+" at [1:1]
```

I suggest you 1st focus on having a `bq` script working statically and once you get the syntax correct you can build the dynamic logic into your working script

Comment: In the working example you have pasted, --job_property=X   What job_property states and how can we use this property? Also is this property stored somewhere in the bigquery metadata?

Comment: You can find it in the log file header, In my example **log.txt**: INFO:googleapiclient.model:body: {"configuration": {"query": {"query": "select count(*) from `mydata-1470162410749.EVALUEX_DEV.projectsJobs`", "useLegacySql": false}, **"properties": {"X": ""}}**, "jobReference": {"projectId": "mydata-147016241074
9", "jobId": "bqjob_r6c50feacc75b8676_00000169293adcf9_1"}}. You can call Google API to get the job to see if it's store on their side as well